# how to access same Session in java and spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

Whenever I request to spring boot controller, new session is created.

I want to keep the same session for a client request because I am storing JWT token in that session and validating user from that session.

Example : On logging in successfully JWT token is generated and sent back to client. In order to access other microservices I am sending the same JWT token to the microservice and storing it in a session. Now when I am trying to request API of that microservice I am fetching the JWT token from the session, but it creating a new session on every request.

Comment: When you say "storing a JWT token in the session", how does the application that's looking up that token identify the user for a new incoming connection? In nearly all cases, the entire point of JWT is that _the client_ should hold on to it and send it with all following requests.

Comment: JWT was designed for session-less applications. if youre using JWT new http session will always be created because youre not storing and returning the session id created by the servlet container

Answer (score 1):

We can control exactly when our session gets created and how Spring Security will interact with it:

**always** – a session will always be created if one doesn’t already exist
**ifRequired** – a session will be created only if required (default)
**never** – the framework will never create a session itself but it will use one if it already exists
**stateless** – no session will be created or used by Spring Security

In our Spring Security configuration :-

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)  // Choose your method here for session creation
}
```

Or in XML:-

```
<http create-session="ifRequired">...</http>
```

Refer Source for more:- [Spring Security Session](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session)

Answer (score 0):

Did you use to fetch to call the services? The session is created by sessionId which store in the cookie. The fetch don't include cookie by default. You cat set {mode: "same-origin"} option in fetch.Maybe that will solve your problem.